# JDBC RowMapper and Casts

Tags: java, jdbc, casting

I have a problem using RowMappers with JDBC (especially `ParameterizedSingleColumnRowMapper`) :

I am querying a list of existing ids from a database with the following :

```
List<Long> existingIds = DS.getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
                         new ParameterizedSingleColumnRowMapper<Long>());
```

The only problem is that my list sometimes does not contains long as expected :

```
// for some value...
System.out.println(existingIds.get(0) instanceof Long); // return FALSE
System.out.println((Object)existingIds.get(0) instanceof Integer); // return TRUE
```

I could just go through `existingIds` and recast the values to `long` but I was expecting the row mapper to do that (I guess `ParameterizedSingleColumnRowMapper` is using `getLong` or something like that and usually it tries to cast to the desired value).

Do you have any explanation or ideas to solve that ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do `ParameterizedSingleColumnRowMapper.newInstance(Long.class)`.  Just creating a new instance directly means it doesn't know the type correctly (it can't infer it from the generics because they get erased at compile time) so it probably just does `.getObject()` which will be at the mercy of the JDBC driver.

Comment: A side note: if you're jumping across databases sometimes the better type might be java.lang.Number. AutoInc in particular returns a variety of Long/BigInteger depending on the driver (or in the case of one horrid driver, an Integer).

Comment: Thanks ! It worked ! I hadn't thought to the type erasure problem that prevented the Mapper from casting but it seems logical indeed.